# How to get NavController.length() after upgrade to ionic 4+?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-router

In Ionic 3, I was able to get the view page stack length using [navController.length()](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/#length)

With the upgrade to ionic 5, [navController is now deprecated](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/reference/migration#navigation) so is there a way to still get the number of pages in the view stack with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic v4 using the Angular RouterModule. So you can get the total count of routes like the below code

> this._router.config.length

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
export class ActionSheetComponent {
  totalRouteCount: number = 0;
  constructor(
    private actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,
    private _router: Router
  ) {
    console.log(this._router.config.length);
    this.totalRouteCount = this._router.config.length;
  }
}
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-tpcyf7?file=src/app/pages/action-sheet/action-sheet.component.ts)